# gridview checkbox select all uplevel and downlevel

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a select/unselect all checkbox in my header template of a gridview. How can I make the select/unselect all functionality work for uplevel and downlevel browsers? Is the check in JavaScript and what do I check for?

Comment: So I had to go lookup uplevel and downlevel browsers and they all seem to reference decade old versions of Netscape and IE. This seems like some kind of old distinction between (what is now) old and REALLY old browsers. Does your page really need to work on something that old?

Comment: Some users choose to disable JavaScript for security reasons.

Comment: If you are saying you have to do it without JS, The only way you could do a select/Unselect all is to submit your page when they click it and handle it all in the code behind.  Personally, I would just do a check to see if users have JS disabled, and tell them they can't use the site without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript.

HTML:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select All">
     <headertemplate>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkMain" onclick="ToggleSelect(this)" ... />
     </headertemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkSelect" ... />
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Javascript:

```
 function ToggleSelect(chk){
    var chkBoxes = document.getElementsByName('chkSelect');

    for(i=0;i<chkBoxes.length;i++){
        chkBoxes[i].checked = chk.checked;
    }
 } 
</script>
```

**Edit:** If you like server side solution, [here is an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.headertemplate.aspx)  not exactly what you need but sure your can modify it to check/uncheck the checkboxes.